# How do we know $X$ and $Z$ are independent in Gaussian Channel

Tags: information-theory

$H(Y|X) = H(X+Z|X) = H(Z|X) = H(Z)$
I am wondering why $X$ and $Z$ are independent.
$X$ is input and $Z$ is noise. How do I prove it??

Comment: Independence (or not) is an assumption that appears in the problem statement. It is not something you can "prove."